# Error saying that DSO missing from command line

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linker, undefined-reference

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_key_delete@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
foreign/c/test/softc/CMakeFiles/foreign-softc-test.dir/build.make:335: recipe for target 'foreign/c/test/softc/foreign-softc-test' failed

make[2]: *** [foreign/c/test/softc/foreign-softc-test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:533: recipe for target 'foreign/c/test/softc/CMakeFiles/foreign-softc-test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [foreign/c/test/softc/CMakeFiles/foreign-softc-test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to symbol 'pthread\_key\_delete@@GLIBC\_2.2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617839/undefined-reference-to-symbol-pthread-key-deleteglibc-2-2-5)

Comment: I do have a CMakeCache.txt but not a CMakelists.txt ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)