# Compiling C++ with CMake: undefined reference to symbol 'nextafter@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: c++, cmake, build, googletest

I have spent the last few days trying to get googletest working on my github repo, and have been running into issues. I am building with cmake, and I am at the end of my rope.

When I build, it consistently fails with the following output:

```
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ryan/src/out
[ 15%] Built target gtest
[ 30%] Built target gtest_main
[ 53%] Built target cpp_utils
[ 69%] Built target gmock
[ 84%] Built target gmock_main
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable run_unittests
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'nextafter@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_unittests.dir/build.make:101: run_unittests] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:237: CMakeFiles/run_unittests.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:244: CMakeFiles/run_unittests.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:182: run_unittests] Error 2
```

I have tried setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` both to compile with `gcc` and `clang` with no improvement. I've also tried adding the `-lm` and `-ldl` flags [directly to googletest's cmakecode](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/7c07a863693b0c831f80473f7c6905d7e458682c/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L140) At this point, I have run out of ideas how to approach debugging - I am still pretty new to cmake.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix it, or even just debug further? My code is *way* too complex for it to be right without tests.

My CMakeLists.txt can be found [here](https://github.com/rwkeane/cpp_utils/blob/BeginTesting/CMakeLists.txt), along with the [script I am compiling with](https://github.com/rwkeane/cpp_utils/blob/BeginTesting/test.sh). And my [entire codebase](https://github.com/rwkeane/cpp_utils/tree/BeginTesting) in general, in case it can help at all. Important parts have been extracted below for clarity:

Full (root) CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# manually set to C++11.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "gcc")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
    "-g2 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wpointer-arith -finline-functions \
    -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables \
    -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security \
    -Wstrict-aliasing -Wcast-align -Wmissing-field-initializers")

# Add first to ensure dependencies are built before they are needed.
add_subdirectory(third_party)

project(cpp_utils LANGUAGES CXX)
add_library(cpp_utils "")
target_compile_features(cpp_utils PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(cpp_utils PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../out)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../out)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../out)

# Testing support
# enable_testing() 
add_executable(run_unittests "")
set_target_properties(run_unittests PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
add_dependencies(run_unittests cpp_utils)

# My source code
include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/googletest/googletest/include
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/googletest/googlemock/include)

add_subdirectory(memory)
add_subdirectory(threading)
add_subdirectory(util)

target_link_libraries(run_unittests gtest_main gmock_main m stdc++)
```

/third_party/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(googletest EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
include(GoogleTest)
```

In the root CMakeLists file, I have tried the following:

- Linking math lib with `target_link_libraries(run_unittests gtest_main gmock_main m stdc++)` as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625627/how-to-link-to-the-c-math-library-with-cmake)
- Linking math lib with `target_link_libraries(run_unittests gtest_main gmock_main -lm stdc++)` as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617839/undefined-reference-to-symbol-pthread-key-deleteglibc-2-2-5)
- Including `-lm -ldl` in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` list
- Adding the -ldl requirement specifically to gtest / gmock with `target_link_libraries(gtest_main INTERFACE m stdc++)` as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153342/cmake-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlsymglibc-2-2-5-even-though-i-link-with)
- Explicitely including pthread as a dependency with `` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137568/undefined-reference-to-pthread-getspecific-when-using-cmake-for-googletest)

Comment: Why are you compiling C++ code with gcc?

Comment: Try not using prebuilt gtest, build your own. I found it to be very sensitive to compiler flag differences (in your build vs how the library was built).

Comment: The proper way to link with math library in CMake is using `target_link_libraries` command. Adding `-lm` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is wrong.

Comment: Note also, that on Stack Overflow we expect the relevant **code** to be in the **question post** itself, not *linked*. This is explicitly noted in the [ask].

Comment: Sorry, looks like I didn't get notifications for these messages. Guess I need to update my settings

Comment: @john I tried with multiple compilers including gcc. I mostly went with that because its what vscode installed for me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am building my own. When I build it as part of my build tree, I get this failure, but when I build it directly from their makefile I do not

Comment: @Tsyvarev I actually tried that and it failed - that's why I ended up with it in the build flag - neither worked. And I will include the code inline if the "closed as duplicate" can't be made to work

Comment: Discovered the issue - and I feel dumb. Looks like `cmake --build ../out --target clean` isn't sufficient and I needed to explicitly get rid of the generated build files and re-build. The code itself was correct in its updated form